# Installing Mongodb PHP Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed mongodb on a new Ubuntu 18.04 server. I can access and work with the database through the command line, but cannot access it via PHP, and was wondering how other people have gotten it to work.

Following a new build of Ubuntu 18.04, and installation of LAMP, I ran:
`sudo apt install mongodb-server php-pear php7.2-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb`

I then added the mongodb.so extension to the php.ini file, and a phpinfo(); page shows mongodb as installed. So far so good.

If I browse to a test php page ($mongo=new Mongo();), the page fails to load though.

Through web searches, I find the https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter page come up a lot, and I have run the composer installation command there, but to no avail.

Installed versions are: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS; mongoDBv3.6.3; php 7.2.17; Apache 2.4.29

I was wondering what steps other people who have gotten PHP to work successfully with Mongodb have followed? I plan to scrap this server and start from a fresh VM install again.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install `php-mongodb` after adding the ppa repository `ondrej/php`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - `php-mongodb` is part of the common Ubuntu package list, so why should one add another repository for it?

Comment: In my case it did not work. Only when I added the ppa repository: ondrej/php was I able to install php-mongodb.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```sh
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're attempting to use the `Mongo` class from the legacy driver, but you're using the non-legacy driver so that class doesn't exist. Please look at the documentation for the updated version of the driver [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). You might also consider using the [MongoDB PHP Library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) to abstract away many of the driver calls.

Please note that there are also compatibility considerations between your versions of the PHP library, MongoDB, and the MongoDB PHP driver. You can find the compatibility information for them [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#php-driver-compatibility).

Comment: Hi, yes I've come across these pages before but to be honest, when it comes to things like classes, compatibility, abstraction, etc, I'm lost. I'm at the point where I just want someone to tell me 'run this then run that'. 

The github page has a composer command which, when I run it, reports 'mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb 1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed'. It then repeats this twice more for mongodb/mongodb 1.4.1 and 1.4.0. My installed version of mongodb is 3.6.3 though, and 'pecl upgrade mongodb' reports 'Nothing to upgrade'

Comment: @user2165827 Simply running `composer install {package}` is going to backfire if there are versioning issues. The error is pretty clear: the version you're attempting to install requires version `1.5.0`, but you have `1.3.4`, `1.4.0`, or `1.4.1`. Take another look at the compatibility table. If you're running MongoDB 3.6, then you need the driver version `1.4.x` or `1.5.x`. If you want to install the PHP library, then you'll need the library version `1.3.x` and driver version `1.4.x` OR you'll need library version `1.4.x` and driver version `1.5.x`.

Comment: Since you're running driver version `1.4.x`, do `composer require mongodb/mongodb:1.3.2` in order to install version `1.3.2` of the PHP library.

Comment: I ran `composer require mongodb/mongodb:1.3.2` and got an error message saying: `mongodb/mongodb 1.3.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed`. So I tried installing version 1.4.0, and got: `mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.`. When I tried installing version 1.5.0, I got a message saying, `Could not find package mongodb/mongodb in a version matching 1.5.0`. Any ideas what should be done next?

Comment: You're clearly running into issues with the installed extension version as it continues to inform you that you're still running extension version `1.3.4`. Please ensure that you uninstall version `1.3.4` and perform an install of a `1.4.x` version of the driver. For example, you can install `1.4.4` via `pecl install mongodb-1.4.4`. After you've successfully upgraded your driver version, run `composer require mongodb/mongodb:1.3.2`. The `composer` command will install the PHP library, NOT the driver. Please be aware of this.

Comment: OK I ran `sudo pecl uninstall mongodb` and then `pecl install mongodb-1.4.4`. `php -i | grep MongoDB` confirms MongoDB extension version => 1.4.4, as does a phpinfo() page. I then ran `composer require mongodb/mongodb:1.3.2, and that seemed to go successfully, without any error messages. If I browse to a php page though containing `$m = new Mongo();`, the page still fails to load?

Comment: @user2165827 I've informed you that the class `Mongo` only exists in the legacy driver. This class does not exist anymore. Please review the [PHP Library documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php) which notes the use of a `MongoDB\Client` class. Also note that you'll need to include the library via `require 'your_mongodb_php_lib_location/vendor/autoload.php';`.